# Deserialize json in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize this json using C#:

```
{"query":
    {"count":10,"created":"2011-06-18T19:15:24Z","lang":"en-US","results":
          {"Result":[{"id":"21373494","Title":"Sushi Bistro","Address":"455 Balboa     St","Rating":
              {"AverageRating":"5"}   
          } 
          {"Result":[{"id":"21373495","Title":"Sushi Bistro","Address":"4565 Balboa     St","Rating":
              {"AverageRating":"1"}   
          } 
    }
 }
```

I tried Newton json.NET, then used JSONHelper class, but it didn't work. Could someone provide a short sample how to deserialize to the object and loop through 'Result' in C#?

UPDATE: sorry for invalid json, ouput is crazy big, so I tried to copy just a small part. However you can see a pattern of Result set in here.

Comment: There is a syntax error. Paste it here: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: That's **invalid JSON**. Please put an effort in your question and provide at least valid JSON string. No parser would be able to deserialize some random bits of characters that do not respect any known serialization transport protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Json provided above is invalid, try to fix json first and after this i guess your code will work.

You can use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) service to validate json.

Example of deserializing json from string using newton json dll:

```
var json = "..";

string output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Comment: so if I have in MyClass public string Title {get;set}, how do I parse output string to grab Title from json?

Comment: @StewieGriffin: I don't remember exactly how, but you can set option that will say ignore json if same property was not found in class. In this case you just need create class with Title property.